# Exception: Cannot open database "WSS_Logging" requested by the login while upgrading SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade

Unfortunately the wss_logging database doesnt exist in my spfarm environment.
and now when I try to run the sp 2013 SP1 and april 2017 CU  , it throws an error saying,

> database not found and login failed for user mdomain\myfarmuser.

is it possible to recover / recreate the wss_logging database. i tried to run the config wizard multiple times, but it was stuck with the below message"

> CanUpgrade [SPUsageDatabase Name=WSS_Logging] failed. (EventID:ajxme)

Exception: Cannot open database "WSS_Logging" requested by the login. The login failed.Login failed for user 'mydomain\myspfarmuser11c'.    (EventID:ajxme)

Cannot upgrade [SPUsageDatabase Name=WSS_Logging].  (EventID:ajxnf)

[image: WSS_LOGGING_NOT_FOUND]

Answer (score 1):

Dis you configure the usage and health service? That is time when logging db created, if it is provisioned try to unprovision if not being used or try to re provision.

Comment: May I know how to re-provision the usage health service. Should I stop that service from manage services from server? N Start again ? Or any power shell cmd to re-privision the same?

Comment: try this one: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/re-provisoning-sharepoint-service-applications-using-powershell1